# Adding "onclick" attribute to fire jQuery code not working (Quotes in string issue)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Right now, I'm working on an ASP.NET application that is adding an "onclick" attribute to an ImageButton control and using straight jQuery as the value. Since the jQuery code is a string, I have to escape the single quotes inside. When I run the application it adds it to the page, but the single quotes end up as '&#39' causing my jQuery to break inside. This is legacy code and I don't want to have to completely re-approach what's trying to be accomplished here. How do I escape the double quotes properly so they're added properly? It is a WebForms applications.

This is what I'm working with:

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick",
                "if($('#" + hiddenTextBoxId + "').val() == '" + GetHiddenText(dataType) + "') {" +
                    "$('#" + hiddenTextBoxId + "').val('" + HiddenInfoPartial + textBox.Text.Substring(5) + "'); " +
                    "$('#" + hiddenTextBoxId + "').focus();" +
                    "return false;" +
                "} else {" +
                    "$('#" + hiddenTextBoxId + "').val('" + GetHiddenText(dataType) + "');" +
                    "return false;" +
                "}");
```

As stated, my problem is that all of the single quotes within the string are being replaced with '&#39' once the application runs it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where's your code? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Just use single quotes in the script

Comment: as @kblok as mentioned, use single quotes. Back in the day, when I used webforms, it was always like: ltlSomething.Text = "<input type='text' onClick='DoSomething();' />"

Comment: If you specifically want to use double-quotes, you can escape them using `\ `. For example, `var stringInQuotes = "\"This string is in quotes!\""`

Comment: Okay, my problem is that I've tried escaping them and they still end up as &quot; and &#39. As the browser renders the tag, it replaces all of those quotes in the string with their corresponding HTML character code.